# MVC4 project blank page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-mvc-routing, iis-express

I've lost the last two hours trying to fix that problem. I can't remember what I've changed to my project but now it is returning a blank page no matter what the URL I write is. No controller is reached, I don't even get any single HTML tag.

I'm running on Windows 7 Starter and I use Visual Studio 2012 and IIS Express. Everything was working fine with this project, I was able to navigate and to access the controllers without any problem. I googled and found several articles suggesting to enable HTTP Routing, and similar HTTP modules in the Add/Removes functionalities section of the Control Panel. I checked all the stuff that are related to IIS but it's not working.

What I really don't understand is that first it was working without any problem and I can't remember which critical change I could have done to this project (I lastly worked on it 2 days ago) And secondly, others project are working just fine so IIS is properly configured. I checked in global.asax and RegisterRoutes is properly called. I haven't changed the default routing system.

I don't have any idea of what I should try since I don't get any error message. I would appreciate any kind of help. Thank you!

**Update 1:** It looks like the MVC framework is never called : nothing happens even if I try to debug and to put a breakpoint at the beginning of the Application_Start() in Global.asax

**Update 2:** Here is my RouteConfig.cs file :

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

And here is my Application_Start function which is anyway never called according to debugging :

```
protected void Application_Start()
        {
            //ModelBinders.Binders.DefaultBinder = new PerpetuumSoft.Knockout.KnockoutModelBinder();
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

            WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "Utilisateurs", "ID", "AdresseMail", true);  
        }
```

(I tried to comment the useless lines (Websecurity since I'm not using it in the controller I'm trying to reach, Knockout and BundleConfig) but I got the same result). But this function is never called anyway.

Comment: sometimes, getting haacked can help http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx/

Comment: I'll check that, thanks!

Comment: Hum, seems that I'm still getting the same blank page. (I installed the package and properly added the key to web.config )

Comment: clear your browser cache. try open in other browser, please post the registered route so we can see which route are being called or being completely ignored..

Comment: If you havent already, try some simple things... Try killing `iisexpress.exe` and restart the app ...also... If not debugging with `IE`, breakpoint may not work.

Comment: try ruling out system by creating a new mvc 4 project

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Ive just posted it. I tried clearing my cache and using a different browser but it didn't solved my problem. I've remembered that one important thing that I have done before yesterday is deleting the asp.net temporary folders for some reason. However the others project continue to work properly.

Comment: I have also cleared the IIS Expres cache as explained here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/scicoria/archive/2013/03/08/cleaning-up-iis-express-sites.aspx and cleaned and rebuild my solution but it's still not working..

Comment: so if you put debug point at--->first line in routeConfig..what happens do the debugger gets called or not..??

Comment: I wanted to know where that blank View coming from.. do you have a static blank page as index..??

Comment: @rcjames Thank you, yes actually I even rebooted my system several times. I used to debug with Firefox as it always worked for me. I tried what you said and I debugged with IE but unfortunately the break point in the application start was still not reached.

Comment: @jenson-button-event Thanks, I've just tried what you said, the newly created project is running fine however when I go back to my project it's still throwing me the same blank page, it's very confusing...

Comment: @Joey Hmmm...do you have multiple projects running in a single solution? If so, it could be that the MVC app (the one you are trying to debug) is not the startup project.

Comment: @Shaz Thanks for your help Shaz, I've just put a break point at the top of RegisterRoute but it's not reached. (I believe that it's normal because Application_Start() is not reached but RegisterRoute is called in that function)

Comment: @rcjames Yes absolutely I have 5 projects in my solution. I'll have a closer look at what you said, I'll come back to you soon. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: @rcjames Well so I checked and my MVC project was properly set as being the startup project. To be sure I even right clicked it and choosed "Debug -> Start a new instance" but I got the same blank page. Well, anyway I was rewriting this project to adopt the onion architecture, i can see that as a good argument to start everything was scratch. I'm very intruigued by this problem but I don't want to bother you any longer with what seems to be a very strange but also a very specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and it turned out my `_ViewStart.cshtml` hadn't deployed to the server. I uploaded that and it worked. Check all your files are up correctly.